# An analytic function is the identity

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

$W$ is a bounded connected open subset of $\mathbb C$. If $\varphi : W \to W $ is an analytic function, such that $\varphi(w) = w$ and $\varphi'(w) = 1$, for some $w \in W$, then $\,\varphi={\rm Id}$.

I'm thinking I need to somehow implement the Schwarz Lemma? But I don't know exactly how to do that here...

Comment: Suppose the specific $w_{0}$ at which $\phi(w_{0}) = w_{0}$ and $\phi'(w_{0}) = 1$ is the origin: $w_{0}=0$, and assume $W$ contains the closed disc $D$ of unit radius with center $w_{0}$.  (If this is not so, a shift and a rescaling of $\phi$ will make it so.)

Now apply Schwarz's Lemma to show that $f(w) = w$.

Comment: Dear @avs, how can we be sure that $\phi$ maps $D$ into itself?

Comment: @KennyWong, you are right.  Perhaps, if $\sup_{w \in D} |\phi(w)| > 1$, then first work with
$$
f(w) = {1 \over \sup_{w \in D} |\phi(w)|} \phi(w) ?
$$
The condition $f(0) = 0$ is still intact, and $$\sup_{w \in D} |f(w)| \leq 1,$$
so $f$ satisfies the premise of the Schwarz Lemma.

Comment: It holds after all – See my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

**First solution.** Without loss of generality, assume that $w=0$, and let $r>0$, such that $\overline{D}(0,r)\subset W.\,$ In $f$ is not the identity, then in $\overline{D}(0,r)$ can be expressed as
$$
f(z)=z+a_kz^k+\mathcal {O}(z^{k+1}),
$$
where $a_kz^k$ is the lowest non-zero term, of order higher than one. Note that  the functions $\,f_n=f\circ\cdots\circ f$ ($n$ times), are also analytic on $W$ and $\,f_n[W]\subset W$, for all $n\in\mathbb N$. Also, it is not hard to see that
$$
f_n(z)=z+na_kz^k+{\mathcal O}(z^{k+1}), \quad\text{for all $n\in\mathbb N$.}
$$
Cauchy integral formula provides that
$$
na_k=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=r}\frac{f_n(\zeta)\,d\zeta}{\zeta^{k+1}}. \tag{1}
$$
If $M=\sup_{z\in W}|z|$, then $(1)$ implies that
$$
n|a_k|\le \frac{\sup_{z\in\ W}|\,f(z)|}{r^k}=\frac{M}{r^k},
$$
and as this is valid for all $n\ge 1$, then $a_k=0$. Contradiction. Hence $f(z)=z$.

**Second solution.** Here we use the additional assumption that $W$ is a *simply* connected region, in which case, $W$ does not even have to bounded. It suffices to be different from $\mathbb C$.

We shall utilise the following results:

**Riemann Mapping Theorem.** *If $\,W \subsetneq\mathbb C$ is simply connected and $\,w\in W,\,$ then there exists a conformal mapping $\,f : W\to\mathbb D$, where $\mathbb D$ is the open unit disk, such that $\,f(w)=0$.*

**Lemma.** *If $g:\mathbb D\to\mathbb D$ is analytic, $\,g(0)=0$ and $\,g'(0)=1,\,$ then $\,g(z)=z,\,\,$ for all $z\in\mathbb D$.*

Assume now that $W\subsetneq\mathbb C$ is a simply connected region, $\,\varphi:W\to W,\,$ analytic, and there exists a $w\in W$, such that $\varphi(w)=w$ and $\,\varphi'(w)=1$. Riemann Mapping Theorem provides an $\,f:W\to\mathbb D$, with
$\,f(w)=0$. Let $\,g=f\circ\varphi\circ f^{-1}$. Clearly, $g$ is analytic in $\mathbb D$, $\,g[\mathbb D]\subset \mathbb D$, and $g(0)=0$ and
$$
g'(0)=f'\big((\varphi\circ f^{-1})(0)\big)\varphi'\big((\, f^{-1})(0)\big)(\,f^{-1})'(0)=f'(w)\,\varphi'(w)\frac{1}{f'\big(\,f^{-1}(0)\big)}\\=f'(w)\,\varphi'(w)\frac{1}{f'(w)}=1.
$$
Using the Lemma, we obtain that $\,g(z)=z,\,$ and hence $\varphi=f^{-1}\circ g\circ f=\mathrm{Identity}.$